# Absolute XML node path / ownerDocument access inside PHP functions called from XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

When calling a PHP function from within an XSL stylesheet in PHP 5.3 (and possibly below), you had full access to the `ownerDocument` of XML nodes passed to the function.

```php
<?php

$xml = <<<EOB
<allusers>
 <user>
  <uid>bob</uid>
 </user>
</allusers>
EOB;

$xsl = <<<EOB
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="allusers">
    <xsl:for-each select="user">
        <xsl:value-of
             select="php:function('test', uid)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOB;

/**
 * Test function
 *
 * @param DOMElement[] $node
 * @return string
 */
function test(array $node)
{
    $output = array(
        'Document element: '.$node[0]->ownerDocument->documentElement->tagName,
        'Node path: '.$node[0]->getNodePath(),
    );
    return implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
}

$xmldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);
$xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
```

The output of this script in PHP 5.3 is:

```
Document element: allusers
Node path: /allusers/user/uid
```

Starting with PHP 5.4 and above, the same script results in:

```
Document element: allusers
Node path: /uid
```

Inside the PHP function, the node path seems to be restricted to a "sandboxed" DOM document with the node itself as the `documentElement`. Interestingly, you can still access the original document via `ownerDocument`, but properties like `parentNode` and XPath queries using `parent::*` or `ancestor::*` will stop at the given node.

Is there any way to regain full access to the `ownerDocument` in PHP 5.4 and above? I couldn't find anything in the PHP release notes that would explain this issue.

**EDIT 1**: Interestingly, it seems possible to access the node's `nextSibling` from within the PHP function, but not its `previousSibling`.

Comment: Forgive me but why would you go this route? PHP being the general-purpose language should be calling XSLT the special-purpose language, sending params if needed. And your PHP functions use DOM operations that XSLT can do. Recall XSLT and XPath are siblings of the [XSL Stylesheet Family](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/).

Comment: @Parfait Explaining the concrete use case would be beyond this issue but please assume that I have to upgrade an existing application to a more recent PHP version. The stylesheets use viewhelper-like extensions written in PHP to run operations that are beyond the purpose (and capabilities) of XSLT, and some of them need to know some context contained elsewhere in the ownerDocument. Unfortunately, it's not an option to rewrite the whole application (even if this would be possible).

Comment: Looks like this bug - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69168&edit=3

Comment: Good spotting, @NigelRen.  And I observe that that bug was filed 2.5 years ago and is still open, with no one marked as assigned to it.  I am inclined to conclude that it has low likelihood of being fixed any time soon, unless someone affected by it takes the initiative to fix it themselves.

Comment: Good catch, @NigelRen! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I assume you're right, @JohnBollinger. I wish I'd be able to hunt that bug myself. Maybe I should try ...